# Mercurial (hg) update error, abort: No such file or directory

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I am unable to update mercurial repos on my machine. I get the following error when I do an update `hg up --traceback`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 87, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 679, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 454, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 733, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 687, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 676, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 385, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 5131, in update
    ret = hg.update(repo, rev)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 395, in update
    stats = mergemod.update(repo, node, False, False, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 554, in update
    stats = applyupdates(repo, action, wc, p2, pa, overwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 329, in applyupdates
    subrepo.submerge(repo, wctx, mctx, wctx.ancestor(mctx), overwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/subrepo.py", line 156, in submerge
    mctx.sub(s).get(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/subrepo.py", line 668, in get
    if self._svnversion >= (1, 5):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 169, in __get__
    result = self.func(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/subrepo.py", line 567, in _svnversion
    output, err = self._svncommand(['--version'], filename=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/subrepo.py", line 555, in _svncommand
    universal_newlines=True, env=env, **extrakw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1239, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
abort: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to do `rm -rf myrepo` and then do `hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myrepo` but that command downloads the repo correctly but I get the same error when hg tries to update the repo to branch default, more specifically I get this:

```
destination directory: foo
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 6270 changesets with 20990 changes to 3682 files
updating to branch default
abort: No such file or directory
```

with trackback, I get an error similar to what I was getting before. I have even tried to re-install mercurial on my system without any luck.

Can you please point to what is the problem. The repo head seems to be alright, (I can `clone` and `update` on other machines), and I am able to `clone` or `update` other hg repos on my system. Can this have anything to do with subrepos? The trackback suggests it.

My system details: 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10, running mercurial version 1.9.1.

Comment: What OS are those machines running? How deep is the directory structure you’re trying to clone into? Also the Mercurial users list may be a better venue for these kind of questions: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MailingLists#The_Mercurial_list

Comment: Thanks Laurens, here's my system config: 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10, running mercurial 1.9.1. I don't know about the depth of the dir structure, but I'd imagine it's less than 15. 

I will post this in the hg maillist too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the source repo has an svn subrepo, and you have no subversion client installed (or svn is not in the search path).

Comment: Thanks! you are right! I just needed to install svn. Thanks again.

Comment: You should file a ticket for this in the Mercurial bug tracker! That error can be handled a lot better. http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker

Comment: And it just got fixed. Mercurial 2.0 should have a better error message.

Comment: Wow Laurens, thanks, I just saw this message, sorry about not doing it. But thanks for taking responsibility

Comment: Mercurial 2.1.1 has the same problem if there's a git subrepo and git is not installed.