# hg Clone of CoolIris fails with "abort no such dir"

Tags: mercurial, abort, cooliris

trying to clone the cooliris project using the command provided by Google;

```
hg clone https://cooliris-toolkit.googlecode.com/hg/ Cooliris-ToolKit
```

but it runs though and always fails with

> updating to branch default abort: No such file or directory

whether I had created the folder **Cooliris-ToolKit** or not.

Can anyone suggest solution for this please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working command:

```
hg clone https://cooliris-toolkit.googlecode.com/
```

https://code.google.com/p/cooliris-toolkit/source/checkout

Comment: Thanks Gael but I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: On this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824297/mercurial-hg-update-error-abort-no-such-file-or-directory, it's said that there was subversion dependencies so you could have to install subversion.