# Mercurial HG: "hg push" returns abort: HTTP Error 500: No such file or directory

Tags: mercurial, repository, push, hgrc

I am using mercurial and when I am trying to use hg push, I am getting this error:

```
abort: HTTP Error 500: No such file or directory
```

Server information:

- Nginx with Mercurial
- Debian 7.1

Any idea why? The pull works fine.

EDIT: By enabling to push with http, I am able to see a stack trace: [error.html](http://www.superupload.com/?d=TA9Q1HVO)

EDIT2: However, if I disable the possibility to use http, the initial error comes back.

**EDIT3: Here is the error when I am doing the trackback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 87, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 684, in _dispatch
cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 466, in runcommand
ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 738, in _runcommand
return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 692, in checkargs
return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 681, in <lambda>
d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 458, in check
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 4338, in push
newbranch=opts.get('new_branch'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1535, in push
ret = remote.unbundle(cg, remote_heads, 'push')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/wireproto.py", line 300, in unbundle
ret, output = self._callpush("unbundle", cg, heads=heads)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 199, in _callpush
r = self._call(cmd, data=fp, headers=headers, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 169, in _call
fp = self._callstream(cmd, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 117, in _callstream
resp = self.urlopener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 890, in http_error_401
url, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 429, in http_error_auth_reqed
self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 865, in http_error_auth_reqed
response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 878, in retry_http_basic_auth
return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: No such file or directory
abort: HTTP Error 500: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 4: The repos hgrc file that is placed in /usr/mercurial looks like that:

```
[web]

deny_push = root, mdpiadmin, www-data
allow_push = milos
contact = Geeks MDPI AG
verbose = true

[trusted]
users = www-data
groups = www-data

[ui]
editor = nano
merge = vimdiff
```

EDIT5: ngnix error log:

Here is the error log on ngnix side when I am trying to do the push:

```
2013/07/29 11:07:45 [error] 14450#0: *19 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 172.16.0.89, server: hg.mdpi.intra, request: "GET /psan2.5-admin?cmd=capabilities HTTP/1.1", host: "hg.mdpi.intra"
2013/07/29 11:07:48 [error] 14450#0: *20 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 172.16.0.89, server: hg.mdpi.intra, request: "GET /psan2.5-admin?cmd=batch HTTP/1.1", host: "hg.mdpi.intra"
2013/07/29 11:07:48 [error] 14450#0: *22 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 172.16.0.89, server: hg.mdpi.intra, request: "GET /psan2.5-admin?cmd=branchmap HTTP/1.1", host: "hg.mdpi.intra"
2013/07/29 11:07:48 [error] 14450#0: *24 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 172.16.0.89, server: hg.mdpi.intra, request: "POST /psan2.5-admin?cmd=unbundle HTTP/1.1", host: "hg.mdpi.intra"
```

EDIT5: Here is the repos ngnix settings:

```
server {
listen              443 ssl;
server_name         hg.mdpi.intra;

ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/hg.mdpi.intra.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/hg.mdpi.intra.key;

root /var/www/hg;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/hg.intra.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/hg.intra.error.log;

auth_basic 'geeks Source Control';
auth_basic_user_file /var/hg/hgusers.passwd;

location / {
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/fcgi.sock;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $uri;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
    fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
    fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
    fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;
    fastcgi_param   AUTH_USER       $remote_user;
    fastcgi_param   REMOTE_USER     $remote_user;
    fastcgi_param   HTTPS           on;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is wrong with the information supplied. Especially the server setup may be causing the problem...

Comment: @UwePlonus, thank you. I added some information. Which details do you need exactly?

Comment: Are there any limitations on the web server about push? By default a push only works with HTTPS, is this correctly configured? It is very difficult to tell what is wrong with your setup...

Comment: @UwePlonus, thanks again. I just enabled the push to works with http and I was able to see a stack trace: I uploaded the stack html file.

Comment: Does the repo have a git or svn sub-repo? Your log is quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7824297

Comment: Hm, no, not the git for sure. For the svn, how can i check that?

Comment: I just installed subversion just in case, but nothing changed, any idea

Comment: If you clone locally, can you push to that? i.e. is it an issue with the http?

Comment: I have already the files locally. So, you mean to create localy a repository and try to push inthere?

Comment: Can you post the http URL of the remote repository or how you invoke the push command? hg push <repo> or just hg push, then you should post your .hgrc, entry for default remote repository.

Comment: Thank you @cinhtau. I am using only hg push, but using hg push <repo> is giving me the same error. Here is the url: https://hg.mdpi.com In which concerns the .hgrc file, I will edit my question

Answer (score 2):

This is only a guess, cause I read you are using nginx with cgi?

Usually you setup the server

> hgweb.config

or each repository

> .hg/hgrc

to allow push

```
[web]
allow_push = *
```

Have a look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep?highlight=%28allow_push%29#Allow_pushing_to_the_repository

---

On your **local** repository in *.hg/hgrc* you will need a default path and the authentication details to perform hg push.

```
[paths]
default = <repo-url>

[auth]
devserver.prefix = https://hg.mdpi.com/
devserver.username = <your-name>
devserver.password = <yout-passwd>
```

I doubt that hg push https://hg.mdpi.com/ will work, cause there is no repo-name in it ..

> hg push https://hg.mdpi.com/reponame

would be legit.

Comment: Could you add some more detail in there please, I am afraid I don't understand what should exactly be done.

Comment: If you entering hg push in the hg repository with above hgrc it won't work. You have to hg push <repo-url> or edit hgrc and add default under paths, so the repository knows where to push. After that you have to provide the credentials for the basic authentication over http. This you can also configure in your hgrc under auth. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tryed to push from the exact repo url and I still have the same problem. Nothing really changed. I also edited the hgrc file in /etc/mercurial but still the same pb

Comment: I am getting this 3 times: `no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 172.16.0.89, server: hg.mdpi.intra, request: "GET /psan2.5-admin?cmd=capabilities HTTP/1.1", host: "hg.mdpi.intra"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34367/discussion-between-cinhtau-and-milos)

Comment: None of the trys to fix this were sucessfull, could we continue testing please?